# Codenameone nested Lead component

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to add `Container A` with lead component into another `Container B` (with its own lead component). However, I cannot figure out how to let `Container A` act separately to pointer events from `Container B`.

The following code is what I've done so far (and failed). To summarize, calling `setBlockLead(true)` on `Lead component A` can cause `Lead component A` to call its own action listener, but will not affect the rest of `Container A`.

```
    Container conB = new Container();
    Button leadB = new Button("b");
    leadB.addActionListener((evt) -> {
        System.out.println("Lead B");
    });
    conB.setLeadComponent(leadB);

    Container conA = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    Button leadA = new Button("a");
    leadA.addActionListener((evt) -> {
        System.out.println("Lead A");
    });
    conA.add(leadA);
    conA.add("Another label");
    conB.add(leadB).add(conA);

    conA.setBlockLead(true); //This has no effect
    conA.setLeadComponent(leadA); //Apparently no effect either
    leadA.setBlockLead(true); 
    //Clicking on leadA (and only leadA) will print "Lead A", but 
    //Clicking on Label will not
```

The major reason for this is to show a Button with Images both above and below the words, which should act differently from clicking on the rest of the container.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support nesting lead components, you can disable the lead component of the internal container by using `setLeadComponent(null)` but nesting won't work as there are a lot of assumptions within the lead component hierarchy.

Comment: Just in case it is helpful to someone, I ended up checking the pointer location in ActionListener of the lead component. The animation is off but at least the event is fired.